# What algorithm to use for splitting 2d skeleton exercises action into repetitions

Tags: python, numpy, math, computer-vision

I am currently using MM-Fit 2D skeleton dataset 2D Skeleton composed of different exercises. I wanted to split the exercises into reps. What algorithm can be used for it to be done?

Here is an example of one of the actions in the dataset:
https://imgur.com/a/kM6XIWa

Comment: the per-frame axis limits (and axes not scaled to maintain squareness) completely distort the pose

Comment: One approach would be to take the Y coordinate of the head (or a hand, or another body part, and use `scipy.signal.find_peaks()` to find the times when the head goes maximally far up.

Comment: @NickODell This approach might be promising. I will try implementing this approach and update my post regarding my findings.

Answer (score 0):

From @NickODells avice, I was able to slice the actions into repetitions using `scipy.signal.find_peaks()`.

I first identify the peaks using the right eye joint as my reference.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
right_eye = excercise_action[:, 14, 1]
peaks, _ = find_peaks(-right_eye) #2D Skeletal is inverted
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(right_eye)
ax.plot(peaks, right_eye[peaks], 'x')
ax.set_title('Right Eye Movement Peaks "{}"'.format(excercise_label))
plt.show()
```

[image]

I then sliced the action based on the the peaks

```
starting_frame = []
ending_frame = []

for ind in range(len(peaks)):
    #print(peaks[ind])
    if ind % 2 == 0:
        # get all starting frame
        starting_frame.append(peaks[ind])
    else:
        ending_frame.append(peaks[ind])
```

The result is this.
[image]